# In Rails, I'm getting a NoMethodError when calling function in new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Action. It looks like this:

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  def register_action(email,type)
    @action = new()
    @action.guid = "123456789"
    @action.email = email 
    @action.action = type 

    action.guid if @action.save 
  end
end
```

If I try and access this class from my user_controller, I get an error. 
The code I'm trying to use is :

```
if (@User.save)
  guid = Action.inspect() 
  guid = Action.register_action(@User.email,"REGISTER")
  MemberMailer.deliver_confirmation(@User,guid)
end
```

Action.inspect() works fine, so I'm guessing that the Action class can be seen, but the line which calls register_action returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError in UserController#createnew
undefined method `register_action' for #<Class:0x9463a10>
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1994:in `method_missing'
E:/Rails_apps/myapp/app/controllers/user_controller.rb:32:in `createnew'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to Rails so apologies for being stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is on this line:

```
guid = Action.register_action(@User.email,"REGISTER")
```

`register_action` is an instance method, not a class method, so you call it on an *instance* of the `Action` class, not the `Action` class itself.

If you want to define `register_action` as a class method, you should do so like this:

```
def self.register_action(email, type)
  # ... Body ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
def register_action(email,type)
```

to either

```
def self.register_action(email,type)
```

or

```
def Action.register_action(email,type)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `register_action` method you need to do `@action = Action.new` instead of `@action = new()`. Alternatively, you can construct it like this:

```
@action = Action.new(:guid => "123456789", :email => email, :action => type)
```

Also, you have defined `register_action` as an instance method on your `Action` class, but you're calling it as a class method by using `Action.register_action`. Change it to:

```
def self.register_action(email, type)
  ...
end
```